# Lucene range query - how to query for a string range with no specific upper maximum?

Tags: lucene

I'd like to perform a range query with Lucene. Normal syntax is along the lines of:

```
{Aida TO Carmen}
```

How do I structure a query such that all values above the minimum are acceptable? I'm using Lucene.Net (2.9.2)

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do this? I'm very interested in the answer as well. It would be so strange if it was not possible...

Comment: I ended up doing it programmatically :)

Comment: Hi there, I'm also interested in the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in Java, you can set the upper bound as null, and it should work: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-dev/22758

I'm personally using Tire in Rails, and I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Before lucene 3.x,You can use RangeQuery like following:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(whichField, new StandardAnalyzer());
Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);
```

see the tutorial for more details:http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-range-query.html

[How do I perform a range query?](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-range-query.html)

[Lucene RangeQuery syntax](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-perform-a-range-query.html)